# Cannot pass properties to a component in a slot in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue.js (v2.1.3) to create nested components but I can't figure out how to bind data between them.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draperd/Lbz6Ly4a/) demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve.

HTML...

```
 <div id="test">
   <comp1>
     <comp2 :message="message"></comp2>
   </comp1>
 </div>
```

JS...

```
    var template = `<div>
      <comp2 :message="message"></comp2>
      <slot :message="message"></slot>
    </div>`;

    Vue.component("comp1", {
      template: template,
      data: function() {
        return {
          message: "Hello"
        };
      }
    });

    var template2 = `<div>
       <span>Message is: {{ message }}</span>
    </div>`;

    Vue.component("comp2", {
      template: template2,
      props: ["message"]
    });

    new Vue({
      el: "#test"
    });
```

If I declare the child component directly in the template of the parent component then the data is passed correctly. But when the child component is assigned to a slot in the parent component then the data is not passed.

I've read and re-read the documentation but can't figure out whether what I want to do is possible and if so, what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use scoped slots, wrap your parent's content in a `template` tag with a `scope` attribute:

```html
<comp1>
  <template scope="{ message }">
    <comp2 :message="message"></comp2>
  </template>    
</comp1>
```

Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbz6Ly4a/1/

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer - I can see that it works fine in the fiddle, but for some reason it's not working for me in the context that I have it (where I'm programmatically building up the DOM and then creating a new Vue on it)... not sure what the difference is, but this has definitely helped me progress, so many thanks.

Comment: @DaveDraper [guide](http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) says this is since `2.1.0`, maybe check your version?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm using 2.1.3